# How can we best :"round up" the most sought-after Keplerian-to-state-vector (and vice versa) answers so they are easier to find?

Tags: discussion

In Astronomy SE there is the question *Where can I find/visualize planets/stars/moons/etc positions?* and @barrycarter's [community wiki answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/13489/7982) has served as a valuable go-to source for finding helpful resources.

Here we have questions regularly about getting positions in $x, y, z$ as a function of $t$ from Keplerain orbital elements, the most recent of which is [How to calculate position and velocity from given orbital elements?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/43530/12102) which received six comments:

- Does this answer your question? [Converting Orbital Elements to Cartesian State Vectors](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19322/12102)
- Or this: [Keplerian Orbital Elements ↔ Cartesian ECEI with WGS84 Corrections](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/12107/6944)
- Or this: [Need help with calculating state vectors from Orbital Elements - C#](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27628/6944)
- Related: [What is this algorithm to calculate orbital state vectors?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/14095/6944)
- Related: [Why are Keplerian elements used in TLEs instead of Cartesian state vectors?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23938/6944)

  1. What would be a good way to round these and any others up into a single canonical post that puts all of the site's "orbital wisdom" related to this conversion in one place?
  2. Might starting a community Wiki on this question be the best place, since the question is so short and simple?

Comment: need help with tags

Comment: Upvoted.  Is there a typo in the title?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a community answer like that would be a helpful resource. Whether the question gets closed or not, it will help people who end up there find the other information more quickly than if they had to dig through the comments.

Comment: I started re-asking this question just now and the extremely useful SE feature (that [also frustrates me regularly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331664/303080)) found this question. I'd like to generate more interest in this. If I added a bounty here, or perhaps asked a new "What are our citable *conversion between Cartesian and Keplerian orbital elements* posts?" and put a bounty on it, might that be one way to generate activity? Awarded bounties in meta still go to the user's reputation in the main site, right?